# How to fix my block and grid layout to handle large data?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to find the closest pair naive algorithm which has 3D coord.

Input is two files which contains 3 floats in one line.

I handled inputs with float3* type variable.

```
float3* teamA;
float3* teamB;
float3* results;

handleFileInput(argv[1], argv[2], teamA, teamB, numPoints);
results = new float3[numPoints[0]];
```

after this, I allocated and copied host data to device like this

```
#define CHECKERROR(val) { if (val != cudaSuccess) {fprintf(stderr, "Error %s at line %d in file %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(val), __LINE__, __FILE__); exit(1);} }

CHECKERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_tA, sizeof(float3) * numPoints[0])); 
CHECKERROR(cudaMemset(d_tA, 0, sizeof(float3) * numPoints[0]));
CHECKERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_tB, sizeof(float3) * numPoints[1])); 
CHECKERROR(cudaMemset(d_tB, 0, sizeof(float3) * numPoints[1]));
CHECKERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_results, sizeof(float3) * numPoints[0])); 
CHECKERROR(cudaMemset(d_results, 0, sizeof(float3) * numPoints[0]));

CHECKERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_tA, teamA, sizeof(float3) * numPoints[0], cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
CHECKERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_tB, teamB, sizeof(float3) * numPoints[1], cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

I set my block, grid like this.

```
dim3 block(512);
dim3 grid(ceil((float)numPoints[0] / 512);

naive_algorithm <<< block, grid >>> (d_tA, d_tB, d_results, numPoints[0], numPoints[1]);
```

My kernel code is simple like this

```
__global__ void naive_algorithm(float3* d_tA, float3* d_tB, float3* d_r, int a_size, int b_size)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx < a_size)
    {
        float min_distance = -1;
        for (int y = 0; y < b_size; y++)
        {
            float i = MUL(SUB(d_tA[idx].x, d_tB[y].x), SUB(d_tA[idx].x, d_tB[y].x));
            float j = MUL(SUB(d_tA[idx].y, d_tB[y].y), SUB(d_tA[idx].y, d_tB[y].y));
            float k = MUL(SUB(d_tA[idx].z, d_tB[y].z), SUB(d_tA[idx].z, d_tB[y].z));
            float distance = SQRT(ADD(ADD(i, j), k));
            if (min_distance > distance || min_distance == -1)
            {   
                d_r[idx].x = (float)idx;
                d_r[idx].y = (float)y;
                d_r[idx].z = distance;
                min_distance = distance;
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
}
```

Environment : RTX 2080Ti

There are five different of data samples :

Team A - 1000000 points / Team B - 500000 points -> Test Failed

Team A - 700000 points / Team B - 500000 points -> Test Failed

Team A - 500000 points / Team B - 300000 points -> Test OK!

Team A - 500000 points / Team B - 100000 points -> Test OK!

Team A - 300000 points / Team B - 100000 points -> Test OK!

In my opinion this caused from thread layout.

Do I have to change the block / grid layout 1D by 1D -> 2D by 2D?
Then how should I set my grid layout?

Comment: This is wrong: `naive_algorithm <<< block, grid >>>`  The grid definition is the first parameter, not the 2nd.

Comment: Oh It was just typo error.. I fixed my code and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Like Robert Crovella said this was just typo error my mistake.

Because one block can handle to 1024 and grid's one dimension can handle to 65535,

if the grid's x dimension : numPoints[0] / BLOCK_SIZE is bigger than 1024 it doesn't works.

Thanks a lot to check my code!